# Retrieve non related records in SQL

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two tables in database

1- File table:
   Fields:

- File_ID
- File Name

2- User Table:

- User_ID
- User Name

Now I have 3rd table which is "File Assigned" which keeps tracks of which file is assigned to which users.

Fields:

- File_ID
- User_ID
- Date

I want to retrieve all non related records i.e retrieve all user that are not assigned to a specific file.

Here is my query for related records.

select * from User i 
join FileRequested r
on i.UserID= r.UserID
where r.File_ID = 1175

Now I want to retrieve all users that are not assigned to that file

Problem: One file can be assigned to multiple users.
I have tried following query but that didn't work

select * from User i 
join FileRequested r
on i.UserID= r.UserID
where r.File_ID != 1175 or r.File_ID is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `NOT IN` with a subquery if I'm understanding correctly:

```
SELECT *
FROM User i
WHERE i.UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID 
                       FROM FileAssigned 
                       WHERE File_ID = 1175)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * From Users as a
Where not exists(select 1 
                 from FileAssigned as b 
                 Where b.UserID=a.UserID)
```